# How to create animation clip via script in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation

I want to create an `AnimationClip` in script against a `GameObject` in Unity. However, I do not know how to do it.

I have attached the following code to a `GameObject` in Cube and pressed the Play button. However, I got an error output.

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
public class LinearExample : MonoBehaviour 
{
    private float m_start_time = 0.0f;
    private float m_start_value = 0.0f;
    private float m_end_time = 5.0f;
    private float m_end_value = 10.0f;
    
    public GameObject cubeObject;
    void Start ()
    {
        Animation animation = GetComponent<Animation> ();

        cubeObject = GameObject.Find("Cube");

        if (!animation)
        {
            cubeObject.AddComponent<Animation>();
        }
        AnimationClip clip = new AnimationClip();
        AnimationCurve curve = AnimationCurve.Linear(m_start_time, m_start_value, m_end_time, m_end_value);
        clip.SetCurve("", typeof(Transform), "localPosition.x", curve);
        animation.AddClip(clip, "Move");
        animation.Play("Move");
    }
}
```

This is an error code:

> MissingComponentException: There is no 'Animation' attached to the "Cube" game object, but a script is trying to access it.
> You probably need to add a Animation to the game object "Cube". Or your script needs to check if the component is attached before using it.
> UnityEngine.Animation.AddClip (UnityEngine.AnimationClip clip, System.String newName, System.Int32 firstFrame, System.Int32 lastFrame) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/artifacts/MacEditor/modules/Animation/AnimationsBindings.gen.cs:400)
> UnityEngine.Animation.AddClip (UnityEngine.AnimationClip clip, System.String newName) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/artifacts/MacEditor/modules/Animation/AnimationsBindings.gen.cs:390)
> LinearExample.Start () (at Assets/LinearExample.cs:24)

### How can I fix this error code?

Also how can I create an `AnimationClip` without playing Unity? This code has a Start function, but I don't want to create the Animation at the same time as Start, I want to use it as an Editor script.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. The animation system without an `Animator` is `legacy`. Enable it and add the clip as follows:

```cs
void Start ()
{
    var _animation = GetComponent<Animation>();

    cubeObject = GameObject.Find("Cube");

    if (!_animation) _animation = cubeObject.AddComponent<Animation>();

    var clip = new AnimationClip();
    var curve = AnimationCurve.Linear(m_start_time, m_start_value, m_end_time, m_end_value);
    clip.SetCurve("", typeof(Transform), "localPosition.x", curve);

    clip.name = "Move"; // set name
    clip.legacy = true; // change to legacy
    
    _animation.clip = clip; // set default clip
    _animation.AddClip(clip, clip.name); // add clip to animation component

    AssetDatabase.CreateAsset(clip, "Assets/"+clip.name+".anim"); // to create asset
    _animation.Play(); // then play
}
```

Comment: Excellent. It worked as desired.
But is there any way to create the AnimationClip from a script before pressing the Start button in Game?

Comment: @gncc I added a piece of code `AssetDatabase.CreateAsset` that generates the animation. To create it in the editor you must use the `UnityEditor` library. (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=491TSNwXTIg) here is brackeys tutorial for help.