# How to create animation clip via script in Editor

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to create an AnimationClip using the Editor in Unity.

[I previously got an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72134528/how-to-create-animation-clip-via-script-in-unity/72135240?noredirect=1#comment127462104_72135240) on how to do that using MonoBehavior.

However, when I run the following code in Editor, I get an error.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;
using System.Collections;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

public class ExampleWindow : EditorWindow {

    private float m_start_time = 0.0f;
    private float m_start_value = 0.0f;
    private float m_end_time = 5.0f;
    private float m_end_value = 10.0f;

    public GameObject cubeObject;

    [MenuItem("Window/ApplyAnimation")]
    public static void ShowWindow ()
    {
        GetWindow<ExampleWindow>("ApplyAnimation");
    }

    void OnGUI ()
    {
        GUILayout.Label("Apply animation", EditorStyles.boldLabel);

        if (GUILayout.Button("Apply animation"))
        {
            ApplyAnimation();
        }
    }

    void ApplyAnimation()
    {
        Animation animation = GetComponent<Animation> ();

        cubeObject = GameObject.Find("Cube");

        if (!animation)
        {
            cubeObject.AddComponent<Animation>();
        }
        AnimationClip clip = new AnimationClip();
        AnimationCurve curve = AnimationCurve.Linear(m_start_time, m_start_value, m_end_time, m_end_value);
        clip.SetCurve("", typeof(Transform), "localPosition.x", curve);
        animation.AddClip(clip, "Move");
        animation.Play("Move");
    }

}
```

The following are the error messages

```
Assets/ExampleWindow.cs(35,31): error CS0103: The name 'GetComponent' does not exist in the current context
```

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

swap lanes and add cube object before get:

```
cubeObject = GameObject.Find("Cube");
        
Animation animation = cubeObject.GetComponent<Animation>();
```

To create animation in asset folder before play button. to review animation cntl + 6 >> play:

```
void ApplyAnimation()
{
    cubeObject = Selection.activeGameObject;

    if (!cubeObject) return;
    
    var _animation = cubeObject.GetComponent<Animation>();

    if (!_animation) _animation = cubeObject.AddComponent<Animation>();

    var clip = new AnimationClip();
    var curve = AnimationCurve.Linear(m_start_time, m_start_value, m_end_time, m_end_value);
    clip.SetCurve("", typeof(Transform), "localPosition.x", curve);

    clip.name = "Move"; // set name
    clip.legacy = true; // change to legacy

    _animation.clip = clip; // set default clip
    _animation.AddClip(clip, clip.name); // add clip to animation component

    AssetDatabase.CreateAsset(clip, "Assets/"+clip.name+".anim"); // to create asset
    _animation.Play(); // then play
}
```

Comment: I got following error. `MissingComponentException: There is no 'Animation' attached to the "Cube" game object, but a script is trying to access it.` To fix this problem, do I have to manually create the animation before executing the script?

Comment: code fully fixed